# Sails Waterline Big file PostgreSQL

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sails.js, waterline

I want to save big files (5Go max) under postgreSQL database, don't ask me why my boss wanted to even if I said it's a bad idea. So now I have to find a working solution.

For now I'm trying this :

```
var file = req.file("largeFile");

    file.upload({maxBytes : 1073741824 },function (err, uploadedFiles)
    {
      if (err)
      {
        return res.serverError(err);
      }
      var fs = require("fs");

      if (uploadedFiles.length > 0)
      {
        var file = uploadedFiles[0];
        fs.readFile(file.fd, function (err, data)
        {
          if (err)
          {
            return res.serverError(err);
          }

          var largeFile = {name : "testFile", data: data};
          LargeFile.create(largeFile).exec(function created (err, newInstance) {

            if(!err){
              res.view("homepage");
            }
          });
        });
      }
    });
```

Application crash at `LargeFile.create` with :

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_0 Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

I try to set --max-old-space-size and --max_executable_size but no luck.

It's possible or impossible mission ?

Answer (score 2):

The error doesn't come from PostgreSQL: It comes from Node.js.

Most likely explanation: your server doesn't have enough RAM memory.

Tell your boss that's not possible with the server you have. Also, every single optimisation possible must be done. Check the DB's source, try making the least variables possibles, etc... 
And trust me, this isn't just a "bad practise". If you want your server to scale to lots of users, you simply can't work with 5GB files on PostgreSQL.

Otherwise, try optimizing your code: Formatting the file's data somehow else, check compression possibilities, avoid too many variable creations and check your code for memory leaks.

I would tell him to give up.

Comment: for now I'm under my mac for dev with 16Go RAM. I just make a test with a 360mo file and same error, I don't think the error is postgresql but maybe I'm missing some node or sails configutation